# GetLogicalDrives выводит не тот результат

Tags: c++, winapi

Я запускаю код

```
#include<iostream>
#include<windows.h>
int main()
{
    std::cout << GetLogicalDrives();
}
```

Он мне выдаёт цифру 12, но у меня есть только диск C он должен быть 2, а 12 это получается L почему он выводит 12 и как мне вывести нужную мне цифру с диском?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlogicaldrives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a bitmask representing the currently available disk drives. Bit position 0 (the least-significant bit) is drive A, bit position 1 is drive B, bit position 2 is drive C, and so on.

Вам перевести?

Гуглопереводчик поясняет:

Если функция завершается успешно, возвращаемое значение представляет собой битовую маску, представляющую доступные на данный момент дисководы. Битовая позиция 0 (младший бит) - это диск A, битовая позиция 1 - это диск B, битовая позиция 2 - это диск C и т.д. 12 - это биты, соответствующие буковкам C и D. DVD-дисковод стоит? Или флешка какая на букву D?

И еще - 12 - это **число**, но **не цифра**!

Запишем 12 в двоичной системе счисления - это число 00...01100, т.е. сплошные нули с единичками на третьем и четвертом местах (начиная с младшего разряда) - соответствующие 2<sup>2</sup> и 2<sup>3</sup> - 4 и 8.

Как уже пояснялось, самый младший - первый - бит указывает, есть ли диск А (нет, тут 0), второй - есть ли диск B (тоже нет, там нолик), затем третий бит - диск C (да, есть, здесь 1), потом - диск D (тоже есть - тут тоже 1), потом диск E - нет, тут нолик, потом F,G,H,... - их нет, все нули.

Значит, в вашей системе активны две буквы дисков - C и D.

Так понятно?

Comment: Да у меня есть подключенный ещё флешка D, но я всё равно не понимаю, как я должен понять какие есть диски если число 12?

Comment: @krime объяснили же `12 <-> 00001100 <-> HGFEDCBA`

Comment: Вот, @krime уже пояснил. Что такое "битовая маска", понятно?

Comment: @Harry Я всё ещё не понимаю, в десятичной системе 12 это C тогда как вы узнали что у меня есть диск D?

Comment: @krime,  так:   `DWORD x = 12, pos = 0;
    char id = 'A';
    while (x) {
        if (x & 1) cout << char(id + pos);
        x /= 2;
        ++pos;
    }`

Comment: См. дополненный ответ... Что вы хотите сказать фразой - "в десятичной системе 12 это C" - это уже не понимаю я. Почему вы вообще решили, что функция, название которой можно перевести как "Дать логические диски", должна давать только один диск C?...